# Accessing content from third party as native posts in Wordpress

Tags: database, wpdb, http

Can Wordpress be architected to use external content accessed over HTTP instead of reading and writing to a database ? Size of the content available remote is simply huge and potentially modified by other tools as well. So importing into database is not a viable option.

Is there any product available that can abstract wpdb layer and use HTTP calls instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is "no". Whatever the API you might use it will be too slow to return a page in a timely manner, unless you have the other HTTP server on your LAN, in which case you should just access its DB directly.

What you can do is cache the "external" content in your DB and serve it the "normal" wordpress way. It means that instead of overriding the `wpdb`class you will need to write code in "higher layer" that will be responsible to sync items from the remote site whenever it is needed.

Other obvious options are to use iframes or oembed to embed the remote content in your wordpress pages.

Comment: Thanks - will explore oEmbed further. We have really huge # (millions) of posts in an external source and would like to leverage WP's front end capabilities/popularity. If we oEmbed the external content, will the user experience be more or less identical to native content ?

Comment: Well, it depends on the quality of embedding, and what is being embedded. In its core oEmbed is a fancy way to automatically insert iframes (most used example is probably youtube videos), but in theory you can insert anything.... the description is just too abstract for me to be able to imagine what is that you actually want to do